# Can we attach Sharepoint Site's List of a Group into Microsoft Teams Tab with the Help of Graph API without using website Tab

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, sharepoint-list

Official Documentation states configuration is not supported for Sharepoint but somehow I managed to configure Planner Tabs on the Teams. So I was thinking if there is a way to attach sharepoint list to the tab using Graph API, I have already used to web site view, that way it asks users to sign in to the SharePoint site every time.

```
`{
    "displayName": "Patient123",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "a43***** some list Id",
        "contentUrl": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/Lists/Books",
        "removeUrl": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/Lists/Books",
        "websiteUrl": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/Lists/Books"
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this "built-in tabs" document over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#sharepoint-page-and-list-tabs. I've linked directly to the SharePoint "lists" section.

Comment: Yes Thanks for the response.. that is where it states that Sharepoint lists to a tab is not supported but so it does for planner tabs but I was able to make planner tab but i could not make one for Sharepoint list.

Comment: If I read it correctly, it doesn't say the _scenario_ is unsupported, just "configuration". Read for example what is says higher up about Wiki pages, that "configuration" isn't really needed. What they're talking about, I think, is that when you add a tab normally to a channel, there is a small popup that appears asking you to set certain things. For instance, for a SharePoint tab, it asks you to choose the site and list. In this case, it's not necessary as you would be setting that directly in your parameters, so the user doesn't need to do anything. Test it out though and let us know